# How do I disable videos in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, browser, privacy

How do I disable all videos from even starting to load, showing a picture from the video, or anything like that, in Firefox.

Anyway, part of the problem with videos is privacy (as with images, third-party scripts, ads, and other things). If I'm loading a third-party's video, the third party can see that my IP address accessed the video from their servers.

Plus, sites would load a lot faster without videos, and I only generally like to watch videos if I'm actually looking for videos to watch.

I'm not just looking to stop videos from autostarting, but I'm looking to stop them from even registering (the same as when images were disabled back in the day). I mean, I don't even want to ping the third-party website for a picture from the video to show in its place while it doesn't run.

Extensions might be an option, but I would need some kind of guarantee that the extension isn't stealing my data.

Answer (score 0):

To Stop the Autoplay of Videos in Firefox:

- Launch Firefox
- In the top-right, click on the three horizontal lines
- Click *Settings*
- Click *Privacy & Security*
- Scroll down to the Permissions section
- Click *Settings* next to Autoplay
- Click on the small arrow button and select "Block Audio and Video"
- Click *Save Changes*.

Videos shouldn’t play automatically any more.

---

To stop the videos from loading requires an add-on.
Some such :

- [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/)
- [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/)

Comment: That doesn't stop the video loading which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Fine, I added some extensions.